# How can Spring have problems with args setting for a bean that has no args?

Tags: java, spring, testing, javabeans

The instantiating class is:

```
@Service("aaa")
public class CustomAaaApiService {
    @Inject
    protected AaaApiKmxImpl aaaApiKmxImpl;
    ....
```

The instantiated class is:

```
@Service
public class AaaApiKmxImpl{
    ...
    @PostConstruct
    protected void init() {
        File userInfoCsv = new File(sprRootDir, USER_INFO_FILE_NAME);
        userInfoCsvEngine = (CSVEngine) context.getBean("CSVEngine", userInfoCsv);
        File userRolesCsv = new File(sprRootDir, USER_ROLES_FILE_NAME);
        userRolesCsvEngine = (CSVEngine) context.getBean("CSVEngine", userRolesCsv);
    }
    ....
```

Both of them are mentioned in the configuration xml file UhradyForIns.xml as:

```
<bean id="aaaApiService" class="amcssz.spr.srv.sec.CustomAaaApiService"/>
<bean id="AaaApiKmxImpl" class="amcssz.spr.srv.sec.AaaApiKmxImpl"/>
```

That configuration is called from the test by

```
@ContextConfiguration({ "classpath:UhradyForIns.xml"})
```

I am getting the output:

```
Error creating bean with name 'AaaApiKmxImpl': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Can only specify arguments for the 
getBean method when referring to a prototype bean definition
```

Why does Spring say it cannot specify arguments when init() has no arguments? The normal launch of the application runs without these problems. Of course, I would get the beans configuration from it, but both these files have no description in any configurations, except that test one.

I don't think the reason could be these creatBean's in the init(), for then the error message will name CSVEngine bean as the bean that could not be created. And the content of init() due to @PostConstruct won't be called at context creation.

---

Oh, sorry, it was my misunderstanding. It falls at

context.getBean("CSVEngine", userInfoCsv);
I checked that by a breakpoint. So, the problem happens in init() without arguments, but due to the call with arguments. I found that due to @tgdavies' question.

Comment: What's the code of your init() method?

Comment: @tgdavies I have inserted content into the code.

Comment: Thank you for your question, it helped. I'll upvote some of your answers.

Answer (score 1):

> Why does Spring say it cannot specify arguments when init() has no
> arguments?

The problem is not related to the injection of arguments in the `@Postconstruct` annotated method, as the post-construct method does not require arguments like you stated.

The problem occurs *during* the invocation of the method; on either one of these lines:

```java
userInfoCsvEngine = (CSVEngine) context.getBean("CSVEngine", userInfoCsv);
userRolesCsvEngine = (CSVEngine) context.getBean("CSVEngine", userRolesCsv);
```

From the XML and Java snippets you provided the beans seem to be defined as [singleton](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch04s04.html) beans (as no bean scope is provided and Singleton is the default). As `context.getBean("beanId", secondArg);` requires the bean to have a scope of type `prototype`, the exception is thrown. From the BeanFactory [JavaDoc](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-beans/src/main/java/org/springframework/beans/factory/BeanFactory.java#L168,L173):

```java
     /**
     * ...
     * @return an instance of the bean
     * @throws BeanDefinitionStoreException if arguments have been given but
     * the affected bean isn't a prototype
     */
    Object getBean(String name, Object... args) throws BeansException;
```

As for the reason why it works during a normal launch but not during tests, I am not sure. The issue could be related to duplicate bean declarations. As both classes are annotated with a `@Service annotation` they might be picked up during [component scanning](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-context/src/main/java/org/springframework/stereotype/Service.java#L36-L37) (as `@Service` annotations themselves have the component meta annotation), while at the same time being declared in the XML. This depends on component scanning being enabled in your project.